# How to throttle bandwidth of SSH connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, bandwidth

How do I limit the speed of an SSH connection? For example, when I am doing port forwarding (`ssh -L ...`), reverse tunneling (`ssh -R ...`), or SOCKS5 dynamic port forwarding (`ssh -D ...`), I may want to limit the bandwidth of the tunnel.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done using `ProxyCommand` which acts as an alternative for the raw TCP connection. You can specify `ProxyCommand` in the global config for `ssh` (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), your private config (`~/.ssh/config`) or in the command line as `ssh -o ProxyCommand=…`.

A trivial `ProxyCommand` is `nc %h %p` or equivalent (use `nc`, `ncat`, `socat` with the right syntax, anything that can give you raw TCP connection to the SSH server). To talk to the server your `ssh` will write to the stdin of this command and it will read from stdout of it. Sole `nc %h %p` is almost like connecting without `ProxyCommand` (when `ssh` does the job of `nc` internally).

The trick is you can insert filters between `nc %h %p` and `ssh`, on both sides. This way you can throttle the connection. Imagine your `ssh` talks through this:

```
pv -qL 20K | nc %h %p | pv -qL 10K
```

What `ssh` sends to the server gets limited by the first `pv`; what `ssh` receives from the server gets limited by the second `pv`.

To run `ssh` that talks through the above command, invoke:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='pv -qL 20K | nc %h %p | pv -qL 10K' …
```

Notes:

- With this method you limit the entire SSH connection, everything that goes through it, all tunnels, X11 forwarding, other sessions (in case of connection sharing), *everything*. You throttle the raw TCP connection.
- If you use `ssh -N` then you may want `pv`s not to be quiet and actually report the throughput of the tunnel(s):

  ```
  ssh -o ProxyCommand='pv -cN out -L 20K | nc %h %p | pv -cN in -L 10K' -ND 8080 user@server
  ```
- With `pv -R` (invoked aside) you can change the settings of a running `pv`, this way you can adjust the throttle anytime. If you want to do this then `pv -P` inside the `ProxyCommand` will be useful to tell what PID belongs to what `pv`. See `man 1 pv` for details.
- If your configuration already uses `ProxyCommand` then you need to embrace the existing value (rather than `nc %h %p`) with `pv`s. If your configuration already uses `ProxyJump` then you need to translate it to `ProxyCommand` and then embrace it with `pv`s.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be applying QoS on port 22 on your router.

[Trickle](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Trickle) is [a lightweight userspace bandwidth shaper](https://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle). It can also be [run as daemon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/trickled), in which role it can manage multiple sessions at a time.

Another possibility is using something like [htb.init](https://sourceforge.net/projects/htbinit/)-script, or [ip_relay](http://www.stewart.com.au/ip_relay/).

According to [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183593/limit-transfer-speed-rate-by-iptables-rules), you could also use iptables to limit the traffic by packets, but that wouldn't be my choice. I'd rather limit the bandwidth directly.