# config file for ssh ProxyCommand after a ProxyJump

Tags: ssh, proxy

There's something really broken about my mental model of how ssh's nesting of ProxyCommand works.

I have the following ssh command that works the way I want it to (ssh to jump.mydomain.com and then once I'm on jump.mydomain.com I ssh (using ProxyCommand) to server.remote.com.

```
ssh -t local_me@jump.mydomain.com                                \
    ssh -o "ProxyCommand='cloudflared access ssh --hostname %h'" \
        remote_me@server.remote.com
```

I feel like I should be able to set up some rules in my local ~/.ssh/config file so that I can just type

```
ssh remote_me@server.remote.com
```

and have these multiple steps "just work", but I can't figure out what those rules should be.

I think my question might be a duplicate of [ProxyCommand use for multiple hops and prompt authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317491/proxycommand-use-for-multiple-hops-and-)
prompt-authentication, but in that question the proxycommands are all being used for simple hops, and my proxycommand doesn't seem to fit into either end of the chain.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really help with my lack of mental modeling about how ProxyJumps and ProxyCommands work and interact, but I did find a way to accomplish the specific task outlined in the question.

After I asked the question I realized that I could come up with an alternate ssh command where the nested ssh was part of the ProxyCommand, as follows:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand=ssh local_me@jump.mydomain.com            \
                         cloudflared access ssh --hostname %h" \
    remote_me@server.remote.com
```

Now I have a single ProxyCommand that I can fit into my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host server.remote.com
     ProxyCommand ssh local_me@jump.mydomain.com cloudflared access ssh --hostname %h
```

And once I've put the ProxyCommand into my config file I can do:

```
ssh remote_me@server.remote.com
```

While I'm happy that I've come up with a solution to my immediate problem, I'm not sure that I've improved my mental model in any way that will help me solve my next conundrum.

Comment: see the manual page `ssh_config(3)` for how `ProxyCommand` works. the client simply uses a pipe to establish the ssh connection, instead of starting a tcp connection itself. i think your solution is the only clean solution, i was thinking of `ProxyJump` but it works with port forwarding and doesn't allow to force using a command (such as `cloudflared`).

Comment: I think some intuition about `ProxyCommand` can be built by observing how one can use it to achieve what goals. I have a nice example here: [*How to throttle bandwidth of SSH connection*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671348/108618).

Comment: @don_aman Minor correction: `ssh_config(5)`. It's `man 5 ssh_config`.