# ssh config: can I replace proxy command?

Tags: ssh-config

Here is my standard work ssh config which everyone uses:

```
host go
  User user
  ProxyJump otherHostname
  StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  IdentityFile ./ssh/key
  ProxyCommand ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -W %h:%p otherUser@OtherHostname
```

The `proxyCommand` part bothers me as the whole point of an ssh config is to have no use for commands.

Are there options for the command parameter which would mean there wouldn't be an ssh command in the config?

#### proxyCommand uses the identityFile and ProxyJump values for the command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -W %h:%p otherUser@OtherHostname
```

#### In other words:

```
ssh -i IdentityFile -W %h:%p differe tUser@ProxyJump
```

Comment: I got this file from a colleague and it was was very messy, the stuff you see there is `host *` which I added to simplify things, so if I understand correctly the ProxyCommand isn't even being executed? There isn't even a port specified and the proxyCommand contain `%p`

Comment: Can you add this as an answer please? and thanks for alleviating my confusion on reading this file. I'll let the guy who made it know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to simplify this type of `ProxyCommand` is `ProxyJump`*. Use `ProxyJump otherHostname` and define all custom options for `otherHostname` in `Host otherHostname` section. (And in case there is `Host *`, mind this: [for each parameter, the first obtained value will be used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116025/108618).)

*But you are using `ProxyJump` already.* The manual states:

> Note that this option will compete with the `ProxyCommand` option - whichever is specified first will prevent later instances of the other from taking effect.

<sup>(source: [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump))</sup>

Your `ProxyJump` is first and it will win. This means you have already replaced `ProxyCommand`, the line with `ProxyCommand` is useless.

---

<sup>* By "this type" I mean `ssh -W %h:%p …`. In general `ProxyCommand` is more powerful, the command can be anything, not necessarily used for actual proxying. E.g. [throttling the bandwidth is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671348/108618)).</sup>

Comment: proxyJump is clearly being used over proxyCommand. Also the parameter for ProxyCommand has a `%p`for port which isn't defined, and this file isn't linked to anything else. Many thanks for clearing this up, I will let the team know, they don't seem to be familiar with ssh-configs